# express.js routing return with 404

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I am learning nodejs and I started with express but when I create a route which is named `movie` it returns with 404 error. But I copied it from express generator's index.js so where is the problem?

**movie.js**

```
    import express from 'express';

const router = express.Router();

/* GET index page. */
router.get('/movie', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index', {
        title: 'Express'
    });
});

export default router;
```

Edit 1

**app.js**

```
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import cookieParser from 'cookie-parser';
import Debug from 'debug';
import express from 'express';
import logger from 'morgan';
import path from 'path';
// import favicon from 'serve-favicon';
import { middleware as stylusMiddleware } from 'stylus';

import index from './routes/index';

const app = express();
const debug = Debug('movie-book:app');
import movie from  './routes/movie';

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));

// db connection
const db = require('./helper/db.js')();
// view engine setup
app.set('view engine', 'pug');
// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
// app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false
}));

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(stylusMiddleware(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', index);
app.use('/api/movie', movie);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    const err = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
});

// error handler
/* eslint no-unused-vars: 0 */
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    // set locals, only providing error in development
    res.locals.message = err.message;
    res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};
    // render the error page
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error');
});

// Handle uncaughtException
process.on('uncaughtException', (err) => {
    debug('Caught exception: %j', err);
    process.exit(1);
});

export default app;
```

Comment: Are you sure you call it with the right URL ? What is it?

Comment: can you add your app.js or the trigger file of your app ?

Comment: I have added app.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you add the router?

```
import media from './routes/media';
const app = express();
/**
 * Add routes
 */
app.use('/media', media);
```

https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html (see end of page)

https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.use

Comment: Yes, I have added

Comment: So you try get /api/movie/movie. Try to change in your router path **router.get('/movie')** to **router.get('/')** and in app.js **app.use('/api/movie', movie);** to **app.use('/movie', movie);**

Comment: hello again, i have changed but still wont work there is my github repo: https://github.com/yosunpasha/movie-book

Comment: @İsmail Enes Datlar, In **movie.js** change ***router.get('/movie', (req, res) => { ...*** to ***router.get('/', (req, res) => { ...*** and it will be working.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using same url in app.js file and you are hitting the correct url.
   if you have created project by express generator:-

```
//Changes in app.js
var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');

app.use('/', indexRouter);
//change above line into below
app.use('/movie', indexRouter);
```

For reference of routing: [Express](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html)

Comment: Hello, adress is correct. But it still return with 404 there is repo: github.com/yosunpasha/movie-book